# export data from sheet1 to multiple sheets using vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to export specific data from one sheet to multiple sheets.

I am not asking to give me the whole code i just need an example to start from

for example: sheet1 has this data

```
      value1  4 
      value2  7                 this goes to sheet named value 


      type of car   Honda       this goes to sheet named car 
      Model         civic 

      category      Exp
      category2     Wo          this goes to sheet named category
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("..\Desktop\test.xlsX")

```
    '~~> Opens Destination Workbook. Change path and filename as applicable
    '  xlWorkBook2 = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\Tutorial\Book1.xlsx")

    '~~> Display Excel
    xlApp.Visible = True

    '~~> Set the source worksheet
    xlWorkSheet = xlWorkBook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    '~~> Set the destination worksheet
    xlWsheet2 = xlWorkBook.Sheets("Sheet5")
    '~~> Set the source range
    xlSourceRange = xlWorkSheet.Range("A1:L8")
    '~~> Set the destination range
    xlDestRange = xlWsheet2.Range("A1:E8")

    '~~> Copy and paste the range
    xlSourceRange.Copy(xlDestRange)
```